# MVC4 Route with Id and Index Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm trying to accomplish the following and receiving the "resource not found" error for #2. Assuming because the routing is not configured correctly.

Desired URLs:

1) domain.com/Customer

2) domain.com/Customer/1 ***Does Not Work**

3) domain.com/Customer/All

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel();

    if (!id.HasValue)
        id = 1; // ToDo: Current Logged In Customer Id

    viewModel.Load(id.Value);

    return View(viewModel);
}
public ActionResult All()
{
    return View(CustomerModel.All());
}
```

My Route Config has the default route setup and I've tried adding an additional route to no avail.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Customer",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I've excluded my attempts at setting up a new route since it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your route would normalize out to **domain.com/Customer/Index/1**.  When you have subsequent parts of the route, you can't eliminate an earlier component just because its value will be the default.  In this case, it's looking for an *action* named "1" which it can't find.

**Edit**:

If your desired route is **domain.com/Customer/ID**, then you can add such a route to your route table:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomerAll",
    url: "Customer/All",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "All" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomerByID",
    url: "Customer/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index" }
);
```

These more-specific routes should come before your default route.

Comment: This worked. I'd tried routes like these without luck...but the trick was moving them not just above the default Customer route but above all the other routes as well.

Answer (score 2):

try to add this route before the default one

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Customer",
    url: "Customers/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**and note that the url starts with Customers not Customer.**

and your desired URL will be : `domain.com/Customers/1` instead of `domain.com/Customer/1`

Comment: This worked too...but I preferred the method from @Rob. Thanks though!